# Selenium 3.x, GeckoDriver, with an existing FF Profile

Tags: c#, selenium, geckodriver

In Selenium WebDriver C# bindings 2.x, we could do this in order to use an existing Firefox Profile:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile("C:\LocationOfExistingProfile", false);
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

I've spent the last many hours looking at documentation, mostly Java oriented, to try and find a way to do this with Selenium 3.x but haven't found a solution. The closest I have found is the Feb. 21st comment https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2645 about using a zip of a profile, but that seems like a poor solution.